# How can I contact the hosted TFS administrator?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to set up a hosted TFS solution on visualstudio.com, but when I try it, it says that my account name is already taken:

[image]

The name is kind of unique, so I'd be surprised if anyone else chose it, but I can't tell because there's no way to learn anything about it. So how can I tell if this name is really used by someone else, or if it's something that I set up and forgot about?

Comment: Have you tried the _Learn more_ link?

Comment: That just tells you more about visualstudio.com and the service, not the account, which is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the accounts that your Live ID has access to at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=309329.

If this is not helpful - perhaps you also are not certain of your Live ID, you can [contact support](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/support/cloud-services-assisted-support-vs) for Visual Studio Online.

Comment: Well I know what I **think** it is, and this one isn't showing up as one of mine. Your support link was very helpful and so I submitted a trouble ticket to them. Thanks.